# My wallet has been giving me an error for several days.....What I Have to do?

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, transfer, transaction, failed

My wallet has been giving me an error for several days...this is not acceptable.
I'm trying to move my USDC to SOLANA. I've been trying for several days. that I have to do?.

Comment: In order for others to help you it's crucial that share the actual error message you are getting.